# How to configure maven to run sonarqube

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, sonarqube

I'm using sonar 3.4 in my linux machine and am able to start the sonar server with `http://localhost:9000`

Now, how to point my maven project to the sonar server for it to start picking up? I've also installed sonar in eclipse4.1 but the association part is still vague.

Is there any tutorial that would help me out with configuring my pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Maven
2. Go to MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml
3. Provide configuration parameters.
4. create a profile to configure "sonar JDBC URL, DB username, DB
   password, sonar URL, any sonar plugin's configuration to analyze
   your source code, provide proxy details, provide repository details
   like nexus or central maven repo to download your artifacts.
5. Save the settings.xml
6. Go to your source code location.
7. Create a pom.xml (a file for MAVEN which says what you need to do
   like build.xml for ANT). Sample pom.xml available online. Customize
   according to your needs.
8. Add MAVEN executables to your path.
9. Run the command as below.

> ***mvn clean compile sonar:sonar***

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not a good idea to put the sonar server configuration into your pom files, as the server access settings should not be shared (e.g. because it requires access to the database). However, all settings are available as properties that could been put into the server.xml file and shared between all projects or you can give these parameters as parameters of the build command (e.g. the Jenkins integration of Sonar does this latter approach).

According to [the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters), the sonar URL is mandatory, while the default database access parameters (url, username, password) point to the built-in database. If you are using other databases, the db access parameters are also mandatory.

You can call a sonar analysis as follows (for a MySQL database, access parameters are of course anonymized):

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.username="sonar" -Dsonar.jdbc.password="sonar" -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar
```

Or you can set them up in the server.xml file [as described in a DZone article](http://java.dzone.com/tips/configuring-sonar-maven).

Comment: Okay.. When I run maven with the command you have mentioned I get the following error :[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:1.0:sonar (default-cli) on project test: Can not execute Sonar: UnsupportedOperationException -> [Help 1]

Comment: According to the documentation, for some reason you are using an old version of the sonar-maven-plugin. The sonar documentation has an example to force the version of the sonar-maven-plugin to a newer version: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-HowtoFixVersionofMavenPlugin